# Retrieving previously uploaded file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am wondering if it is possible in MVC4 (.net 4.5) to upload a file to the server and save it to memory. Then in a separate form post, collect that file and deal with it at that point.

I need to be able to upload a file on one part of my page and then be able to submit some form details on another, but be able to access the file I have just uploaded. For logical reasons, I cannot have the file posting at the same time on the main form. They must be separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you could store the file in *memory* session, there are a few risks in doing so:

- What if someone resets the app pool or the web server?  That data will be lost
- Can the user upload a large file?  Will lots of small files be uploaded?  You need to make sure you can handle the memory requirement

If these aren't concerns, then feel free to store the file in session:

```
Session["UploadedFile"] = someByteArray;
```

If these are concerns, then I would suggest:

- Store the file on disk and fetch it when you need to
- Store the data in session with a database

Comment: For what I require this solution is the most appropriate and will try this first, thanks! Forgot I could use Session to store a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer have some great explanation. I just wanted to add something.

On the first page, save the file on the HD but also store the filename/id in the database. Now you have an ID that points to the current uploaded filename. This ID can be transfer between pages with type="hidden" input or through a Session variable.

If you don't have a database, the filename could be the ID.
ex: generate a guid, have the filename saved with this guid ex: [guid].xls

Comment: I did consider this but thought it may be an overly complex way of achieving it. It looks like the number of ways of achieving this are limited and I also like this approach. Thanks

Comment: @user2743684 Yeah... and when using sessions, everything is stored on the server ram so if multiple user put information in sessions it can grow pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you'll be saving the form data from your 2nd form along with a path to the saved file (or the binary itself) another option is to save your data twice.

Upon POSTing the uploaded file, save your file as you were planning on originally and get the ID/reference for that new record.

Your next form would simply be saving the updated form data to that same ID.